# elastic search 6 - use one or two type in one index?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I use, create two index or what?
I have one entity goods and one entity shop, should I create two index or two type in elastic search 6?
I have tried two mapping two type but it throw Exception.
How Can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In elacticsearch 6, you cannot create more than one `doc type` for an index. Earlier for an index `company` you could have doc type `employee`, `infra`, 'building' etc but now you it will throw an error.
In future versions doc type will be completely removed, so you will only have to deal with index.

An **index** in the elasticsearch is like **table** in normal database. And every **document** that you store will be **row**, and **fields** of that document will be **columns**.

Without seeing the data and knowing what you want to accomplish it is pretty hard to suggest how you should plan the schema of elasticsearch, but these information can help you decide.

Comment: thank you i will use this suggest An index in the elasticsearch is like table in normal database

Comment: welcome. let us know if you have more confusions. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use one of these two options:

1)Index per document type
2)Custom type field

for option 2:

```
PUT twitter
{
  "mappings": {
    "goods": {
      "properties": {
        "field1": { "type": "text" },
        "field2": { "type": "keyword" },
      }
    },
    "shop": {
      "properties": {
        "field1": { "type": "text" },
        "field2": { "type": "date" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[see this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html#_index_per_document_type)